# Auto Fill login details on computer startup

Tags: python, batch-file, autofill

I was wondering how i could create an application which  would auto fill in all application details upon computer start up and login, saving me spending 10 mins filling in login details. For instances, auto fill and login the Steam Portal.

any suggestions are helpful, would batch file or python suit for this? this is mainly for fun and learning outside of school, but i haven't tried anything outside of C#.

Any help or tutorials are appreciated

Comment: you can automate IE explorer with powershell/jscript/vbscript. You can automate other browsers with Selenium and java or javascript. For desktop applications you can check AppActivate function and powershell/jscript/vbscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too broad question but for simple tasks you can use the similar script as this bellow.It will start and 'login' you into the notepad.You can detect the application to send keys to by its title , and send keys like enter and tab to switch between elements and enter them.Highly depends on the application you want to use:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
        @echo off 
        mode 15,1 
        timeout 3 >nul
        start "" notepad 
        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" 
        exit /b %errorlevel% 
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 

var sh=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
WScript.Sleep(3000); 
for(;;){ 
        WScript.Sleep(3000); 

        if (sh.AppActivate("Untitled")){ 
                sh.SendKeys("user{TAB}pass{ENTER}"); 
                WScript.Quit(0); 
        } 
}
```

more info - [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx)

Comment: thanks @npocmaka, its a start! i know its kind of broad but as i say its kinda of a learning experience, with your answer i can attempt to learn from there,  i just needed a starting point :)